# How can I edit FlatBuffers file?

Tags: tensorflow-lite, flatbuffers

I am using TensorFlow Lite.

The converted model file does not work on some mobile device due to its NNAPI driver's bug.

In order to avoid the bug, I need to insert reshape op before fullyconnected op.

I inserted it into the original model but an optimizer in the converter removed it.

How can I edit the tflite model file?

I tried to convert it to json by `flatc` command, but it seems hard to change the topology of model by hand.

The ways to prevent optimizing of the converter are welcome, too.

Thanks.

Comment: Certainly converting a FlatBuffer to and from JSON is the only reasonable way to edit it, as you can't usually edit it in binary. Generally whoever maintains the specific FlatBuffers schema (in this case TFLite) would provide tools to edit the data, I'd ask on their repo.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended that you don't update the TFLite file without using existing libraries, if any. You can add a feature request in the TFLite converter so the team can take a look at it in detail. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TFLiteConverter&template=60-tflite-converter-issue.md